# Django two databases for two apps in one project. Haw to make migration correctly?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I wanna use 'db1' for app 'app1', and  'db2' for 'app2'. 
(I don`t need any synhronization between ths applications and databases. They independent but lay in one 'mysite' django project.)

I have migration for 'db1' in 'app1'. 
/app1/migrations/0001_initial.py. It contain classes for 'db1' ('default') structure.

Now
- I appended database 'db2' to settings.py DATABASES dict. 'app1' use 'default' database. (db1 is 'default')
- I made $startapp 'app2' folder
- I put 'app2.apps.App2Config' to INSTALLED_APPS list
- I executed $makemigrations app2
app2/migrations/ folder is empty (only **init**.py where)
Any makemigrations exectuions now write:

> No changes detected in app 'app2'

I running $migrate --datbase=db2
It writing:

> Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: admin, auth,
>   contenttypes, db1, sessions
>
> Running migrations:    Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
>   Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
>   ....
>   ....
>
> Applying db1.0001_initial... OK

And nothing is changing. No any mention about 'db2', no migrations upgrade as i see, the app2/migrations folder is empty yet.

What i have to do for make models for 'db2' and use it in 'app2' code?
Thanks

Comment: Nessasary to 'makemigrations' for app2 with DATABASE_ROUTERS in settings.py: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/
'migrate' function work without one, but 'makemigrations' must have router.py file with Class App2Router(object) spcified for 'app' & 'db2'. If makemigrates has completed - 0001_intial.py present, and now may to migrate --database=db2 - it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nessasary to 'makemigrations' for app2 with DATABASE_ROUTERS in
settings.py: [docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db][1]

'migrate' function work without one, but 'makemigrations' must have
router.py file with Class App2Router(object) spcified for 'app' & 'db2'.

If makemigrates has completed - 0001_intial.py present, and now
you may to migrate --database=db2